# How to remove profile info step during signup process in socialengine4 php framework?

Tags: php, socialengine

Well I am wondering to know about How can I remove profile information step from signup process in socialengine4 PHP framework.

I just want only create account step.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this sql command in your database:

UPDATE `engine4_user_signup` SET `enable` = '0' WHERE `class` = 'User_Plugin_Signup_Fields'

Comment: thanks..i have found already but i was trying to find any process in admin..and there is nothing like this in admin..yuukkkkkkk..but still this is good way..Thanks for reply